# Is the maximal temperature of the curlicue fractal acheived by $e\times\gamma$?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, fractals, irrational-numbers, open-problem

The [Curlicue Fractal](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CurlicueFractal/) is defined as follows:

Choose an irrational number $s$ and a horizontal unit segment with angle $\phi_0 = 0$. Define $\theta_{n+1} = \theta_{n} + 2 \pi s \pmod{2 \pi}$, with $\theta_0=0$. To the previous segment, add a new unit segment with angle $\phi_{n+1} = \theta_{n} + \phi_{n} \pmod{2 \pi}$. The resulting series of line segments is the curlicue fractal. The "temperature" of these fractals measures the boundedness of these curves.

$s = e\times\gamma$ creates a very high temperature for this fractal, far greater than all the millions of other irrational numbers I've tried.  Does any other irrational number beat it?

[image: curlicue fractal with high temperature]

Comment: Is $\gamma$ Euler's constant?  If so, are you sure $e\gamma$ is irrational?

Comment: So ... $\phi_n = n(n-1)\pi s$ (mod $2\pi$), right?

Comment: If $e\gamma$ is rational, I'll be shocked. If the curlicue fractal is used to prove that, then I'll be triply shocked.

Comment: Is there a "standard" number of iterations at which one takes a curve's temperature?  I seem to see the temperature keep climbing w/ the number of iterations.  Or perhaps I'm doing something wrong.  I don't quite get the tabulated temps for pi,e,etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Refined Solution -- A Red Hot Curlicue

A more elegant variation on my previous solution is 
$s=55\sqrt{2}+92\sqrt{5}\>$ 
which reaches a temperature of approx $T=226\,000$ near $l=1\,060\,000$.
Note that numerically $s=(567/2)-\!1.39499...\!\times\!10^{-7}$.

[image: Red Hot Curlicue]

And yes, that is an actual plot -- I didn't just make a huge `Point[]`.

At $l=2\,000\,000$ I get the following. (Which for some odd reason differs from what Ed Pegg gets for what should be the same thing. I'm wondering if there are round-off issues somewhere.)

[image: Red Hot Curlicue l=2000000]

---

### Previous Solution

Sort of a cheat, perhaps, but, assuming I've made no mistakes, $s=1/2+\pi/10^6$ will give a temperature of approx $T=10\,000$ at $l=47\,000$

[image: Curly 1/2 + Pi/10^6 @ 47,000]

Note that the slight deviation from $1/2$ will eventually come further into play, dropping the temperature. Eg, at $l=100\,000$ we have (not to the same scale)

[image: Curly 1/2 + Pi/10^6 @ 100,000]

The temperature for the curve for the first $100\,000$ steps is

[image: Curly 1/2 + Pi/10^6 Temp to 100,000]

Similar curves w/ increasing powers dividing the $\pi$ should allow arbitrarily high temperatures to be reached.

Comment: I suppose there should be a rule against that, but definitely valid.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to exclude such things except on a subjective basis of "elegant-ness".

Comment: I've found a more elegant example, and edited it into the post.

Comment: Huh... now why does that work so well?  Amazing.

Comment: Ah, the continued fraction!  1792125 third term.  Very interesting.

Comment: (91/10)^(1/4) - 7/4 works well

Comment: 12/(Root[-2 + 4 #1 - 6 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^24 - E^(Pi Sqrt[163])) ~ 0.4999999999999999780983596  will have an extremely high temperature. 
 About 806715 at 1115000 steps.

Comment: My take on it was this: s=1/2 (mod 1) just bounces back and forth forever. s=1/2+epsilon is observed to slowly rotate until the epsilon finally builds up enough "oomph" to become disruptive, rather than just perturbative.  The smaller the epsilon, the longer this takes.  I just searched through a few simple linear forms looking for something very close to an integer plus one-half.

Comment: Huh... When I compute 12/(Root[-2 + 4 #1 - 6 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^24 - E^(Pi Sqrt[163])) // N , I get 0.09375

Comment: Try *** // N[#, 50] &  instead.

Comment: That's really odd... Why the difference?  And it's not just a matter of precision because I get approx 0.5 for any number I put in instead of 50 for the precision on the second form.  Why is the vanilla //N different?  Also, an s that close to 0.5 by my figuring should give something much more compact than that 30 jointed figure you display in your post.  I can replicate something like that w/ the 0.09375 value though.

Comment: Odd... I get w/ Mathematica 10.4.1.0 Linux x86 (64-bit):   

s = 12/(Root[-2 + 4 #1 - 6 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^24 - E^(Pi Sqrt[163]));
{N[s], N[s, 10], N[s, 25], N[s, 50]}   ==>

{0.09375, 0.5000000000, 0.4999999999999999780983596, 
0.49999999999999997809835961220599939554054558394194}

Comment: Yikes! You're taking the difference of two numbers of order 10^17 to get a result of order 100.  No wonder the numerical evaluation has trouble.  But why do the different forms of N[] differ so much?  Do they propagate to inner levels of the computation differently?

Answer (score 2):

The value $s = e\times\gamma$ reaches a maximum temperature of **2433.73** at 460024 steps.  For awhile, this has been the highest achieved temperature.

Three identical maximal squares can be placed in an equilateral triangle. The [Calabi triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CalabisTriangle.html) is the only other triangle with that property.

[image: Calabi Triangle]

$x^3+x^2-7x+1=0$ with $x\approx 2.10278...$ has a temperature of **4408.7** after 2005399 steps, a new record.  The ratio of sides in a Calabi triangle is $(x+1)/2$.

Here's the Calabi Curlique Curve after 2005399 steps:

[image: Calabi Curlique Curve]

Can anyone find an irrational value with a temperature higher than **4408.7**?

And Somsky has the answer, go for extreme continued fractions. Best I've gotten so far is 12/(Root[-2 + 4 #1 - 6 #1^2 + #1^3 &, 1]^24 - E^(Pi Sqrt[163]), about
0.4999999999999999780983596122, continued fraction 0, 2, 11414670114816032, 39, 1, 2, 12, 1, 12178299, 1, 1, ... I estimate it will take 20 quintillion steps to break out.  Here's the first million steps:

[image: High temperature curve]

Here's 2 million steps of Somsky's curve:

[image: Somsky's curve]

Wild.